# cell.Offset(0, 1).Value2 return unusable value?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new to VBA so bear with me please.  I have a simple spreadsheet with three columns where I'm taking a businessname, city and state (Cols 1, 2 and 3) respectively, and using them to call a WhitePages API to extract some additional data.

If I hard code the values it works fine...

`url = "http://api.whitepages.com/find_business/1.0/?businessname=ABBOTT LABORATORIES;city=NORTH CHICAGO;state=IL;api_key=key"`

If I use `Value2` for the business name, it also works fine...

`url = "http://api.whitepages.com/find_business/1.0/?businessname=" & cell.Value2 & ";city=NORTH CHICAGO;state=IL;api_key=key"`

But if I start to use `Value2` for anything after the businessname it fails completely.

`url = "http://api.whitepages.com/find_business/1.0/?businessname= " & cell.Value2 & ";city=" & cell.Offset(0, 1).Value2 & ";state=" & cell.Offset(0, 2).Value2 &    ";api_key=key"`

When I `MsgBox` all three values they look just fine, so I'm getting the right data.

Upon `XMLImport` this basically returns, oddly "Success" and "The search did not return results."

What am I missing?  I've also tried to actually change the active cell and extract the data that way, instead of using offsets, but that didn't work either.

Is there something with the offset that's returning a value something other than I can use?

Even a workaround would be appreciated!

Comment: just a thought..Dim a variable and write it out. Verify your returning the value you expect..

Comment: the value of `cell.Offset(0, 1)` is not what you think it is.  Leading/trailing spaces or returns perhaps? Try adding `Debug.Print "|" & cell.Offset(0, 1).Value2 & "|"` and inspect the result in the immediate window

Comment: Thanks - I did try both of these.  I did Dim a variable as a String and it didn't do the trick.  I was hoping maybe it was some non-string type.  I also added the brackets and nothing extraneous is showing - the brackets are right up against the values.  This is going to keep me up all night :-/.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your Value2 to a string before:

```
CStr(cell.Offset(0,1).Value2)
CStr(cell.Offset(0,2).Value2)
```

And MsgBox these strings results, to know what is the values returned.

Comment: Thank you.  I tried both of these and added brackets, and the values returned look just fine...      city = "[" + CStr(cell.Offset(0, 1).Value2) + "]"
  MsgBox city
  state = "[" + CStr(cell.Offset(0, 2).Value2) + "]"
  MsgBox state

Comment: URLEncode is a method to convert a String to an another String encoded for url passing parameters. You should add this method and call it for each parameter you send via URL. The code sample for URLEncode will be found at [URLEncode](http://sevenwires.blogspot.fr/2009/07/code-encode-url-in-excel.html). Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`url = "http://api.whitepages.com/find_business/1.0/?businessname= " & Trim(cell.Value) & ";city=" & Trim(cell.Offset(0, 1).Value) & ";state=" & Trim(cell.Offset(0, 2).Value) & ";api_key=key"`